# How do we distinguish "through, by" under the meaning of "by way of"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

A practice for differentiating "by, through, in, with" goes like this:
"He relaxes himself ____ exercise."

I do know that the blank should be filled with "through" or "by doing" through my feel of the language.

As for "with, in", I know clearly the reason why to disuse them here: with: usually followed by tangible tools in: usually followed by intangible and abstract nouns

But I can hardly clarify the difference between "by and through" under the meaning of "by way of".

Many thanks to whom can expound it!

Comment: 'With' would not be wrong in this context; it can mean 'by means of'. (NB "The reason why I should not use them.' If a building or machine is _disused_ it has ceased to be used at all; _disuse_ doesn't mean _avoid using in a particular case_.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and note!